# Relationship between paint, paintComponent, repaint, etc

Tags: java, swing

The `paint` method:

```
Invoked by Swing to draw components. Applications should not invoke paint directly, 
but should instead use the repaint method to schedule the component for redrawing.

This method actually delegates the work of painting to three protected methods: 
paintComponent, paintBorder, and paintChildren. They're called in the order listed 
to ensure that children appear on top of component itself. Generally speaking,
the component and its children should not paint in the insets area allocated to the
border. Subclasses can just override this method, as always. A subclass that just 
wants to specialize the UI (look and feel) delegate's paint method should just 
override paintComponent.

Parameters:
    g the Graphics context in which to paint

public void paint(Graphics g)
```

I've read many times not to override `paint()`, but to override `paintComponent()` instead.  As seen above, the documentation also suggests to override `paintComponent()` if you want to specialize the UI.

So, I wanted to trace through the code to see why this is so.

```
 protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
 {
     if (ui != null) 
     {
         Graphics scratchGraphics = (g == null) ? null : g.create();

         try 
         {
             ui.update(scratchGraphics, this);
         }
         finally 
         {
             scratchGraphics.dispose();
         }
     }
 }
```

There are many methods to trace through, but for conciseness, here's `update()`:

```
public void update(Graphics g, JComponent c) 
{
    if (c.isOpaque()) 
    {
        g.setColor(c.getBackground());
        g.fillRect(0, 0, c.getWidth(),c.getHeight());
    }

    paint(g, c);
}
```

An overloaded version of `paint()` is called, and `paint()`, itself, calls `paintComponent()`.  So, I guess I'm just trying to figure out what's going on here exactly.  I'm very new to Swing; there are a lot of classes and it's pretty difficult to trace through all of them, especially with my limited knowledge of using GUIs, in general.

Are these methods constantly calling each other, thereby giving the *illusion* of an image on the screen?  If so, why does it matter so much if you override `paint()` instead of `paintComponent`? I imagine that my logic is in some way flawed or lacking, considering that for applications, the documentation advises against invoking `paint()` directly, and instead suggests to invoke `repaint()`. So, basically, I'm just trying to get some insight into the overall relationship between `paint()`, `paintComponent()`, `repaint()`, etc.

Comment: Also, if anyone knows of a good book/tutorial on Swing/AWT, that would be great.  I want something that really goes deep into the subject matter.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you read through [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)? The important considerations to remember is that `paint` is responsible for calling `paintComponent`, `paintBorder` and `paintChildren`. Overriding `paint` can compromise your component's ability to work properly. `paintComponent` is responsible for painting the "bottom" layer of the component.  For something like `JPanel`, this means painting the background (if opaque)

Comment: (continued) for something like `JTable`, this means painting the rows and columns and cell values...

Comment: Also, recommend the 2 links provided by @MadProgrammer. `Overriding paint can compromise your component's ability to work properly` - not sure I understand that statement, especially if you invoke `super.paint()`.

Comment: @camickr Cause most people (who post here) don't :P - so it's a "risk"

Comment: @SteveP. : Try [__Filthy Rich Clients__](http://filthyrichclients.org/), it is a good reference book regarding painting material in `Swing`. Though I guess, it needs to be referred once you have visited those Java Tutorial links as already pointed.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you for the references/explanation.  I've seen the latter, but the former looks very helpful (haven't been able to read through it all yet).  One more thing:  is `paint`, `repaint` constantly being called, but so fast that we can't see it?  Or are they only called when an update is necessary?

Comment: @nIcEcOw thank you, too.  I will check it out.

Comment: @SteveP. `repaint` requests may be consolidated by the `RepaintManager` in order to reduce the number of actual paints that take place.  But your paint routines should be optimised as much as you can to return quickly (so don't go loading images or other resources in the `paint` - for example)

Comment: @SteveP. Also, +1 for an excellent and important question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly take a look at...

- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and
- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

The second should be compulsory reading for all Swing developers.

`paint` is (within the context of this question) the top level method called (`update` is actually called first, which just forwards to `paint`) when the `RepaintManager` wants a component to be painted.

`paint` is responsible for (amongst other things) calling `paintComponent`, `paintBorder` and `paintChildren`.  If you're not careful you could compromise your components ability to paint.  So if you HAVE to override `paint`, make sure you are calling `super.paint`.

It's important to note, the if a child component is updated, the parent component may not be repainted, so it don't try and use `paint` to provide overlays for your component.

`paintComponent` is responsible for painting the "background" of the component.  This basically delegates to the look and feel.

In the case of something like `JPanel`, it will fill the background with the background color (if set to opaque).  In the case of something like `JTable`, it will paint the rows, columns and cell values.

It is very important to ALWAYS call `super.paintComponent`, especially when dealing with transparent components.

`repaint` will make a request to the `RepaintManager` which may consolidate the paint requests so as to reduce the actual number of paint events that are raised.  This helps improve performance.

The important thing to note here is that you don't control the paint process, so don't try, work with it instead.

Your `paint` method is also expected to run quickly, so avoid time consuming operations, like loading resources, or compound loops where possible.  If you can, create backing buffers and paint those instead

ps- Paint is fun ;)